# Why does verifying a Facebook access token sometimes result in a 400 response?

Tags: facebook, access-token

Our users can give us permission to do offline posts for them.  We have them log into their Facebook account via a popup Facebook login, and they grant us these permissions: publish_stream, offline_access, manage_pages

We fetch an access token.

We fetch a list of wall & fan pages and associated access tokens to which the user has administrative access via:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=[access token]
```

Our user chooses which Facebook pages for us to post to, and we store the associated Facebook user id , page/wall names and access tokens

Prior to posting a message to the user's wall / fan page(s), we verify that the associated access tokens are still valid:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[facebook user id]/?access_token=[access token]
```

Most of the time, this results in a response where we can parse out whether or not the access_token was accepted.  Occasionally, however, Facebook responds with a 400.

Any ideas on why we sometimes get a 400 response?

Comment: Usually there is a textual error message in the response body as well. (If you don’t _get_ a response body, then that might be due to how you are making this API call.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  the error details are: {"error":{"message":"Unsupported get request.","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100}}  There is a lot of discussion on how permissions issues can cause this, so I'm looking for ways to reproduce